# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jdbc.teradata' didn't find subcontext 'jdbc'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'jdbc/teradata'

Tags: spring, jdbc, teradata, weblogic12c

However I could open up the required remote port for `Teradata`, I am getting this error, is it because the required jdbc driver library is missing in the Weblogic in which I am deploying my Application.

Please advise, you can find complete error below. Because of this failure consecutive `Spring Autowired Components` are also failing.

```
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teradataDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/async-db-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jdbc.teradata' didn't find subcontext 'jdbc'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'jdbc/teradata'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: Yes you are right, issue is with **jdbc.teradata** Spring is not able to find this context that's why it is not able to create the required bean. Try including required JAR file in your CLASSPATH.

Comment: I had just interacted with one of my colleague, it seems like required `datasource` needs to be created in `Weblogic Admin Console`. All the jdbc db driver jars are present he says. I should be thorough now I hope. Thanks.